# Magento 2 : Extending layout xml wont work

Tags: magento2, category, layout, catalog, view

I'm struggling to extend some layout XML.

I want to add a custom subs.phtml o=in `catalog_category_view.xml`.

I created `app/design/frontend/Template/Template/Magento_Catalog`, modifications in templates folder work fine but I can't change anything in the layout folder.

I created `catalog_category_view.xml` and added this:

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View" name="category.subs" template="Magento_Catalog::category/subs.phtml"></block>
```

But it is not working.

I created another file in `layout/override/base/catalog_category_view.xml`
but it removes every phtml from the template.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Can you add the file path for your XML please

Comment: Also I will rename your question as overriding is working fine for you, it's extending that you're having an issue with.

Comment: Also, where have you added that line? It will only render automatically if the parent is a container.

Answer (score 0):

Create `app/design/frontend/Template/Template/Magento_Catalog/layout` directory and create `catalog_category_view.xml` file. add below content

```
  <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View" name="category.subs" template="category/subs.phtml">            </block>
```

then, create `app/design/frontend/Template/Template/Magento_Catalog/templates/category` directory and create `subs.phtml`

Then add your logic into `subs.phtml` then clear cache and call.

it should work, let me know if you have any issue.

Comment: Did it, cache cleared, but nothing new.  I can edit some existing file in templates/category like products.phtml but the xml wont call any new file. I activated the template hint debugger and subs.phtml wont show.

Comment: @Matthieu Herdegen your layout  file and template with path

Comment: app/design/frontend/Template/Template/ Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_category_view.xml app/design/frontend/Template/Template/ Magento_Catalog/templates/category/subs.phtml